# mysql duplicate entry with different values

Tags: php, duplicates

I am running the two following queries on a table where the refId table is unique.  As you can see the refId values that are going in are different but I am getting the following error

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 2

INSERT INTO eve_journal(`date`, `refID`, `refTypeID`, `ownerName1`, `ownerID1`, `ownerName2`, `ownerID2`, `argName1`, `argID1`, `amount`, `balance`, `reason`) VALUES('2011-07-12 00:56:00','4597105986','85','CONCORD','1000125','Qzack','90288778','Josameto','30000156','12956.00','365344321.02','11717:3,17057:1,17060:2,17065:1,17076:2,17081:2,23989:2,')


INSERT INTO eve_journal(`date`, `refID`, `refTypeID`, `ownerName1`, `ownerID1`, `ownerName2`, `ownerID2`, `argName1`, `argID1`, `amount`, `balance`, `reason`) VALUES('2011-07-12 00:52:00','4597093172','34','Shigakarri Niromochi','3012152','Qzack','90288778','Shigakarri Niromochi','3012152','18400.00','365331365.02','No reason specified.')
```

Perhaps I do not understand what unique and duplicate mean or maybe I am missing the point of a unique table.  To help guide your answers, I have the refID set to unique because it is the only thing other than the day that is getting put in that is guaranteed to be different.  How ever with the way the data is pulled, it is possible to pull the same entry more than once.  I want to prevent duplicate entries and figured I could do it with mysql saying no.

Comment: Can't understand what you want? You have made refID unique OK, but what you mean by "it is possible to pull the same entry more than once"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the data type on your refId column isn't large enough so it's getting shrunk down to the max size of an INT. Increase that either to an UNSIGNED INT or to a BIGINT.

Comment: Also, you could of course store it as a string if it's coming from an external system.

Comment: Wow you are fast, i was just typing a similar answer.  It was my understanding that with most languages that if you exceded the largest number of a variable type that it would wrap around.  I guess mysql is different (not a programming language either lol)  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Haha glad you got it worked out. Here's some MySQL documentation on the behaviour it uses for overflow handling: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html

Answer (score 2):

The error state that the duplicate value is 2147483647, which is the maximum value of the field as declared in the DB. the two values to insert are larger and are probably capped to the max.

Solve it by increasing the field size on the DB